# how to call CompletableFuture supplyAsync(() with executor service in for loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> this.restTemplate.exchange(join(restAPI URL), POST,
                new HttpEntity<>(requestObj.toString(), httpHeaders), String.class), executorService)
        .thenAcceptAsync(response -> deleteRow(response, deleteCount), executorService)
        .exceptionally(error -> {
            logger.error("Error :: " + error);
            return null;
        });
```

This is my old code when i am sending list of data in requestobj . if it requestobj  is huge then i want to split it into more List then I want to call the Rest API depends on the spilt  multiple time .
how to do this without changing the CompletableFuture.supplyAsync?